# Dicionário key-value

Tags: python, dicionário

Supondo que eu tenha o seguinte dicionário:

```
dicionario = {'exemplo1':1, 'exemplo2':2, 'exemplo3':3}
```

Como eu faço pra adicionar uma chave-value sem alterar as que já foram adicionadas?
No caso eu quero que fique assim:

```
#Como eu quero
dicionario = {'exemplo1':1, 'exemplo2':2, 'exemplo3':3, 'exemplo1':100}
```

Tentei de algumas formas aqui, mas eu só consigo fazer com que ele atualize o valor da chave que já foi adicionada.. ficando assim:

```
#Como fica:
dicionario = {'exemplo1':100, 'exemplo2':2, 'exemplo3':3}
```

Comment: Adriano, é importante você saber que cada chave dentro de um dicionário é única... Ou seja, você não pode ter duas chaves `exemplo1`... Se você atribuir um valor a uma chave já existente você sobrescreverá a mesma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pode ter duas chaves com mesmo nome. Se quiser adicionar casos com chaves *diferentes* você pode usar o método *update*:

```
my_dict = {'exemplo1':1, 'exemplo2':2, 'exemplo3':3}
my_dict.update({'exemplo4': 4})
```

Comment: Qual é a vantegem de usar `dict.update()` para atribuir apenas uma chave sobre `dict['chave'] = valor`? Isso não afetaria a performance do seu código?

Comment: Update não tm nad a  ver com performance - tem a ver com, se as chaves e valores que você vai atualizar estão como dados (você recebeu um dicionário com novos dados em uma função, ou leu os valroes das chaves que vai atualizar de um arquivo), contra - já saber, na hora de escrever uma função, quais chaves ela vai atualizar - daí o nome da chave pode estar direto no seu arquivo .py, como parte do programa. Em termos de performance, a diferença é negligível para qualquer lado.

Answer (score 2):

Antes de mais nada, uma característica do dicionário é ter UM valor para cada chave diferente. Se quiser dois valores, precisa usar outra estrutura (ou usar uma estrutura no lugar do valor simples). Quando você repete uma chave, está sobreescrevendo o valor anterior.

Sobre adicionar, é basicamente isso:

```
dicionario['novachave'] = 'novovalor'
```

Aplicando ao seu caso e testando:

```
dicionario = {'exemplo1':1, 'exemplo2':2, 'exemplo3':3}
print(dicionario)
dicionario['exemplo4'] = 100
print(dicionario)
```

**IMPORTANTE**: note que mudei o nome da chave para evitar sobreescrita

Tem outras maneiras, como por exemplo o método `update` mencionado na resposta do Lucas. O update é mais interessante se quiser acrescentar mais valores:

```
my_dict.update({'exemplo4': 100, 'exemplo5': 500})
```

Veja as duas maneiras funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/kJqAjk)**.

### Manual:

> https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Show! Eu tinha lido sobre isso, mas precisava confirmar. Valeu mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Como mencionado, uma chave é única, mas nada impede que você tenha uma lista como valor; assim, pode guardar múltiplos elementos por chave. Pela consistência e simplicidade, eu usaria um `defaultdict` de lista:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
my_dict['exemplo1'].append(1)
my_dict['exemplo1'].append(100)
my_dict['exemplo4'].append(1337)

print(my_dict)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'exemplo1': [1, 100], 'exemplo4': [1337]})
```